# Why aren't python's strip and lstrip methods behaving as expected in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, strip

I'm trying to remove some junk from messy CSV strings and I don't understand why strip and lstrip aren't behaving as expected.

I am expecting this to return "ABC" but can't seem to strip these characters.

```
>>> a = '","ABC"'
>>> a
'","ABC"'
>>> a.strip('",')
'ABC'
>>> a.lstrip('",')
'ABC"'
```

Comment: To be precise, you expect the output of each of the last two commands to be `"ABC"`?

Comment: I expect the input ","ABC" to return "ABC" when stripped of ",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `a.lstrip('",')` removes all `','`s and `'"'`s at the beginning of `a`. (*Left* strip.)
- `a.rstrip('",')` removes all `','`s and `'"'`s at the end of `a`. (*Right* strip.)
- `a.strip('",')` removes all `','`s and `'"'`s at both sides of `a`.